# Вводное ли это выражение?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Подчас необратимо то, / Что было уж совершенó. / Но в большинстве своём времённом(,) / Ты, думачи, / Что нету боле продолженья / И что конец пришёл всему, / Ещё имеешь посейчас / Исправить что-то / Дивный шанс.

Comment: Из пяти заданных вопросов ни одного принятого.  Зачем тогда спрашивать, если ответы вас не устраивают.

Answer (score 0):

Наречное выражение ***"в большинстве своем"*** [временном] не выделяется запятыми. Стало быть, его распространенный вариант тоже не будет требовать знаков при себе.

---

Есть ответ специалистов на этот счет:

> Всегда ли нужно выделять запятыми сочетание " в большинстве своём"?
> Пример - "Современная молодёжь в большинстве своём в одном слове две
> ошибки делает".

Answer (score 0):

Подчас необратимо то, / Что было уж совершенó. / **Но в большинстве своём времённом,** / Ты, думачи, / Что нету боле продолженья / И что конец пришёл всему, / Ещё имеешь посейчас / Исправить что-то / Дивный шанс.

1. Обычно, к примеру, говорят: **люди в большинстве своем**, то есть большинство людей. Такие сочетания не обособляются.

*Молодые люди **в большинстве своём** ради карьеры и успешной жизни стремятся переехать из маленьких сёл, посёлков и деревень в большие города. **В большинстве своём** собаки привыкают к своему хозяину, а кошки ‒ к дому. Сочинения, написанные в начале года учениками одиннадцатого класса, **в большинстве своём** удостоились лишь удовлетворительных оценок.*

2. Но что такое **"в большинстве своем времЁнном"?** Не зная значения этого сочетания, нельзя говорить о его обособлении. Может быть, "пребывая в большинстве своем времЁнном"? Тогда обособление требуется.

Таким образом, это обстоятельство, но нужна ли его **актуализация**, то есть подчеркивание? Это может решить только **автор**.

Стало быть, нужно **уточнить вопрос у него.**